# Mandatory parameters, Dapper and System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: c#, dapper

I am using `Dapper` to call a stored procedure which have a mandatory parameter `@idProject`

this is my code fragment:

```
using (var c = _connectionWrapper.DbConnection)
      {
        var result = c.Query<Xxx>("dbo.xxx_xxxGetPage", new { @idProject = 1 }).AsList();
        return result;
      }
```

Should work but raise an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Procedure or function 'xxxGetPage'
>   expects parameter '@idProject', which was not supplied.

Why?

Comment: remove the `@` and see if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing the `CommandType`.

```
using (var c = _connectionWrapper.DbConnection)
{
    var result = c.Query<Xxx>("dbo.xxx_xxxGetPage", new { idProject = 1 }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).AsList();
    return result;
}
```

By default, dapper uses Text.

https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var result = c.Query<Xxx>("dbo.xxx_xxxGetPage", new {1}).AsList();
```